# jQuery working as expected in IE8 but not in Chrome... need someone to look over my code

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8

I have recently been updating a site so that it looks nearly as good in IE8 as it does in Chrome. I have managed to get the corners applied correctly, but if you take a look at http://clarkeyboy.zxq.net/test_longcatalogueitems.htm you will notice that the catalogue rows appear as expected in IE8 but not in Chrome. In Chrome they appear to go on forever.

Could somebody please take a look at the jQuery / css in the above page and tell me where they think I am going wrong? I am sorry that I wasnt able to shorten the CSS files - they are generally quite huge but all the styles (or at least most) are needed in that page, to demonstrate the problem.

I have also noticed some weird behaviour on localhost which I appear to be unable to reproduce on the above page. It appears that some of the time the page displays perfectly in Chrome, sometimes the catalogue rows appear slightly shorter and sometimes they go off the page. I dont get why this is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Richard

PS if anyone has any tips on how I could improve my code but still achieve the same effect then please say so.

I am particularly interested in any hints on how I could achieve the jQuery stuff that I am doing with the catalogue rows without JavaScript. I basically have an image of unknown size (the width and height of the img tags are put in by looking at the image on serverside and scaling it down if it is bigger than the maximum thumbnail size) and I would like to get the description to span the full height and up to 20px away from the image.

Comment: Try refreshing the page a few times. I find that sometimes it appears correctly but most of the time it doesnt. Its kinda weird.

Comment: hmm I have just tried uncommenting lines 74 and 75 (`$(this).html($(this).html() + " " + newWidth);` and `$(this).html(newWidth);`). It seems that it sometimes returns 727 (when it displays correctly) and sometimes returns 1717. This is on a 1920 * 1080 screen.

Comment: Well it's a little hard to tell what's going on, but I can't make it do anything bad. One thing I note is that those commented-out calls to "animate" appear to be written as if they're synchronous; they're not. When you call "animate()", it *schedules* the animation but returns immediately.

Comment: Turns out what I was seeing was a result of using `document.ready`, rather than `document.load`, as bobince stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting properties based on the widths of images in the document, and you're doing it on document-ready.

The document ready pseudo-event fires some time after the HTML DOM has been populated; it does not guarantee all the images are loaded. On Chrome and other browsers that support the HTML5 DOMContentLoaded event, the document-ready callback will typically occur sooner than on other browsers, meaning more chance the images haven't loaded yet.

If you want to call a function when everything in the page, including images, is ready, you should be using the load event (`$(window).load(function() { ... });`). Although I don't really know why you're messing around with scripted layout here as I don't immediately see anything on that page that couldn't be done with simple CSS.

Comment: I see your point but the images have their widths and heights set in the html tag (`width='x' height='y'`). Surely it should return those widths instead of what appears to be a negative number... I will try changing it to `.load` and see what happens.

Comment: They don't have `width`/`height` attributes, they have sizes set by CSS style. This doesn't affect the `width`/`height` attribute/property.

Comment: Width / height does still work (judging by the output if the image is larger than the maximum size), even though they have long been deprecated. I have been meaning to replace them with the `style="width: x; height: y"` method (since it varies from image to image) but have not got round to it - this was just something I put in so that I could check that the scaling function would do what I wanted it to do.

Comment: I just realised that I am not actually using the width and height attributes - I am actually using `style='width: x; height: y'`. Anyway changing ready to load solved the problem. Thanks!